# MATLAB: For-Loop Increment

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab

I'm trying to use a for-loop in matlab where there is an increment of 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, etc., but I don't understand how to that.

I've tried something like this:

`for i = 0.1: "step" : 10^-10`

`% do something`

`end`

I don't know what to put in "step." Can someone explain if there's a way for me to solve this?

Comment: In this case I would use something like this: set $i=1$. Then, after every iteration $k=1,2,...,10$ divide $i$ by $10$, that is $i=i/10$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i = 10.^[1:-1:-5] disp(i); end
```

works perfectly in displaying

```
 10
 1
 0.10000
 0.010000
 0.0010000
 0.00010000
 0.000010000
```